# storing data into an arraylist of objects cross classes

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist

I am struggling on trying to iterate through a resultset and being able to store the records I retrieve into an ArrayList of objects from my class Threat.java. I am a fairly beginner programmer who has been sorta thrown into a big java project so unfortunately, I haven't had a consistent learning experience so my understanding of how to make this process work is lacking. Database.java handles all database procedures (connecting, getting result set, assigning fields), and MainDisplay.java is where I want to do the majority of my work, at least for now. Threat.java has multiple variables but I'm only concerned about being able to successfully print server_id for now.

The error I get is at the line where I have my add() method in MainDisplay which reads:"The method add(Threat) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (void)"

Can anyone help shed some light on my situation? I think I have my organization muddled up as well as struggling to understand how exactly to add fields by method instead of through arguments.

**update:** I made changes to public String setServer_Id(String server) but still have the same error

**Database.java**

```
public class Database {

String details = null;
ResultSet rslt = null;
private int threat_level;
private String target;
private String server_id;
private int client_id;
private String attacker;
private String num_this_attack;

Connection con;
public void createConnection() {

    //sensitive info

}

public ResultSet getData() {

    String query =  "SELECT target_stats.server_id, target_stats.target, target_stats.threat_level, target_stats.client_id, attack_stats.attacker, attack_stats.num_this_attack " +
            "       FROM target_stats " +
            "       LEFT OUTER JOIN attack_stats " +
            "       ON target_stats.target = attack_stats.target " +
            "       WHERE target_stats.num_attacks > '0' " +
            "       AND target_stats.interval_id>'2'";
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        rslt = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rslt;    

}

public void process() {

    try {


        server_id = rslt.getString("server_id");
        target = rslt.getString("target");
        threat_level = rslt.getInt("threat_level");
        client_id = rslt.getInt("client_id");
        attacker = rslt.getString("attacker");
        num_this_attack = rslt.getString("num_this_attack");
        //details = "Target IP: " + target + " Server ID: " + server_id + " Client ID: " + client_id + " Threat Level: " + threat_level  + " Attacker IP: " + attacker + " Number of attacks: " + num_this_attack;
        //System.out.println(details);


    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public String getServer_id(){
    return server_id;
}
```

**Threat.java**

```
public class Threat {
private String server_id;
private String target;
private int threat_level;
private String client_id; 
//ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> attackerXnumberY = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

public Threat(){
    server_id = null;
}

public String setServer_Id(String server){
    server_id = server;
            return server_id;
}

public String getServer_Id(){
    return server_id;
}


}
```

**MainDisplay.java**

```
public class MainDisplay {

private static String serverHolder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Database Data = new Database();
    //Threat threat = new Threat();
    ArrayList<Threat> StatusInfo = new ArrayList<Threat>();

    Data.createConnection(); //Create connection to database
    Data.getData(); //Runs query and returns result set

    try {
        while(Data.rslt.next()){
            Data.process();
            serverHolder = Data.getServer_id();
            //StatusInfo.add(threat.setServer_Id(serverHolder));
            Threat threat = new Threat();
            StatusInfo.add(threat.setServer_Id(serverHolder));
            System.out.print(StatusInfo);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method:

```
threat.setServer_Id(serverHolder)
```

returns void, nothing. So it makes no sense to add a "void" into an ArrayList. You need to think through just what you're trying to add to the list, and then change your code accordingly.

You need to give your Threat class a decent constructor, and use the information from the database to create a *new* Threat object, and add *that* to the ArrayList.

Comment: I didn't have it void before, but when it wasn't void, it gave an error. Eclipse suggested to switch it to void or make it a constructor. neither really made sense to me but when I made it void the error went away.

Comment: @solleks: You need to create a Threat object (it seems), and for that, you should make a constructor. While compiler error messages are helpful, you need to use the information but not blindly follow it. Using void is not going to help you here.

Comment: @solleks: your changes make no sense. What good is a String going to do you here? **Again** you need to give the class a **constructor** and use it to create a *new* Threat object. Not sure how to make it more clear. If the recommendations are confusing, then please ask for clarification, but please don't just ignore them.

Comment: I read your comment after I made changes. I'm and trying to think and really digest your help before I write nonsense as a constructor. Please remember I'm very new to java and have been thrown into a project without much say or choice.

Comment: @solleks: OK, well again make your constructor, one that takes a serverHolder parameter and create your Thread object -- Question solved. Then study Java some more because you're going to want to do intense studying to catch up. The [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html) can help you there.

Comment: I wanted to try to avoid passing data through parameters because later on, each object will have a 2D arraylist and I thought that there would be problems at the point. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
        StatusInfo.add(threat.setServer_Id(serverHolder));
```

You need to add `Threat` objects to an ArrayList but above line of code is trying to add void returned from `threat.setServer_Id(serverHolder)`